# Is there any way to get a UTC time conversion for a future point?

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows, I can do a UTC conversion easily enough by calling `GetTimeZoneInformation`. The struct I get back as a result will have two different bias values, one for standard time and one for DST, and a `BiasCode` representing which one we're currently on.  And that's just fine if we only care about the current moment.

But I've got an API that the user calls to retrieve data about upcoming events.  The data is stored in the database in local time, and the user wants it in UTC, so I run the conversion and everything's fine... except that we're coming up on a time change in a few weeks.  And if I report events on the other side of the time change with today's bias, they'll be off by an hour.

Is there anything I can call which works like `GetTimeZoneInformation`, except that I pass it a date and time then the the `BiasCode` that it gives me is the one that *will be correct at that time,* instead of the current one?  (And yes, I know the rules change from year to year. I'm not looking for anything that looks beyond a few weeks into the future.)

Comment: There's no Win32 function I know of that does exactly what you want, but it shouldn't be difficult to write your own using GetTimeZoneInformation for the current year, or GetTimeZoneInformationForYear for dates in future years (Vista and above).

Comment: Note that conversion from local time to UTC time can be ambigious. Ideally, you should store as UTC and convert for display.

Answer (score 2):

[`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - let me quote MSDN -

> Converts a time in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) to a specified
>   time zone's corresponding local time.

You can supply both past and future input UTC time and get local time conversion taking into consideration all details about DST settings at that specific moment in time.

`TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime` is a twin function to do reverse conversion.

The problem that look even more important for me is that DST settings change from time to time even for the same region, and conversion might be different from year to year (this, certainly, mostly affect events in past, not in future). I assume that this API takes care of this as well, tracking the history of DST rule changes over time.

UPD. The assumption is correct and MSDN mentions that:

> - The time zone uses a different UTC offset for the old and new years.
> - The UTC time to be converted and the calculated local time are in different years.